# Angular loop from the received data from JSON

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angularjs-scope

I pass array ImageList to view

```
  res.render('imagelist', { title: 'Imagelist',listImages:imageList });
```

In view there are this skope (for example):

```
 $scope.planets = [
                    {
                        name : 'Mercury',
                        distance : 0.4,
                        mass : 0.055
                    },
                    {
                        name : 'Venus',
                        distance : 0.7,
                        mass : 0.815
                    }
]
```

How I can add data from `listImages` to the scope in the loop?

Past one varible to scope:

```
 $scope.planets = [
                    {
                        name: <%- JSON.stringify(title); %>,
                        distance: 0.4,
                        mass: 0.055,
                        test: 'test'
                    },
                ];
```

But I need to send the array (first code part).

Question: I need to pass array (List) to Angular frontEnd. There I use a table with filtering.
There I use a table with filtering. This table will get data from the scope (See the example above).
But I want to transfer an arbitrary number of rows in a list and display them in a table. How can I do that? I need a cycle in scope, but I do not understand how to write it.

Table code:

```
<table>
    <tr><th>Name</th><th>Average Distance</th><th>Mass</th></tr>
    <tr><td><input ng-model="f.name"></td><td><input ng-model="f.distance"></td></td><td><input ng-model="f.mass"></td></tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="p in planets | filter:f"><td>{{p.name}}</td><td>{{p.distance}}</td><td>{{p.mass}}</td><td>{{p.test}}</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question? unable to get your question exactly..

Comment: I update a qwesteon. I need pass unknown number of entries in the list and use it in scope to add to table.

Comment: Where is your template code for binding them into a table? it would be better to assist if you create a error scenario in plunker.

Comment: See the update.